# How ways to return to "void" kind?

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

I'm using on windows phone 8.1

```
try
{
    var Url = "https://...../oauth/authorize?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("4a3e...") + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:8888/callback") + "&show_dialog=true";
    var StartUri = new Uri(Url);
    var EndUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/callback");

    WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(StartUri, EndUri,null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
}
catch (Exception Error)
{
    //
    // Bad Parameter, SSL/TLS Errors and Network Unavailable errors are to be handled here.
    //
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(Error.Message);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Because `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue` is `void` kind so 
I cant put `var t=WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue` on

I just want to return below code

```
public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
{
    WebAuthenticationResult result = args.WebAuthenticationResult;

    if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
        //OutputToken(result.ResponseData.ToString());
        await GetUserNameAsync(result.ResponseData.ToString());
    }
    else if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
    {
        throw new Exception("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + result.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + result.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your need to return bool true/false from your authentication method and if it is true proceed else stop.

Answer (score 1):

void is not a "type" it just means that the method has no returned value. You do not need a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since its not good practice to return void in async methods:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started

you should simply replace void with Task

```
public async Task ContinueWebAuthentication(
```

Comment: It still stoped at  WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(StartUri, EndUri,null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);

Comment: don't keep run.public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)

Comment: I still on spotify auth... Login ok